# Cannot pass object to database;detached entity passed to persist

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I'm new in jpa and hibernate, and it took me a while to set up the xml file(it might not be whole), lower the errors, and try to figure it all out. I'm using mariadb and have a database called jpadb, which im trying create and pass an "Employee" object from java. I get the error

> :org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to
>   persist: model.Employee

my code is as follows:

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

    <persistence-unit name="sample" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

        <class>model.Employee</class>


        <properties>


            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/jpadb" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />


        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sqlDemo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>loader.MainApp</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.17.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.17.Final</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



</project>
```

**Employee.java**

```
package model;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table (name="user")
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int eid;

    @Column(name = "ename")
    private String ename;

    @Column(name = "salary")
    private double salary;

    @Column(name = "deg")
    private String deg;

    public Employee(int eid, String ename, double salary, String deg) {
        super( );
        this.eid = eid;
        this.ename = ename;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.deg = deg;
    }

    public Employee( ) {
        super();
    }

    public int getEid( ) {
        return eid;
    }

    public void setEid(int eid) {
        this.eid = eid;
    }

    public String getEname( ) {
        return ename;
    }

    public void setEname(String ename) {
        this.ename = ename;
    }

    public double getSalary( ) {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(double salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getDeg( ) {
        return deg;
    }

    public void setDeg(String deg) {
        this.deg = deg;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [eid=" + eid + ", ename=" + ename + ", salary=" + salary + ", deg=" + deg + "]";
    }
}
```

**CreateEmployee.java**

```
package service;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import model.Employee;

public class CreateEmployee {

    public static void main( String[ ] args ) {

        EntityManagerFactory emfactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory( "sample" );

        EntityManager entitymanager = emfactory.createEntityManager( );
        entitymanager.getTransaction( ).begin( );

        Employee employee = new Employee( );
        employee.setEid( 1201 );
        employee.setEname( "Maria" );
        employee.setSalary( 40000 );
        employee.setDeg( "Technical Manager" );

        entitymanager.persist( employee );
        entitymanager.getTransaction( ).commit( );

        entitymanager.close( );
        emfactory.close( );
    }
}
```

I'm trying to go through tutorials, but due to hibernate-property version mismatches I'm having a really hard time. It took me a while to find the properties for mariadb in order for this to work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer guys, I recreated my table and it seemed to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set **@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)** and remove the line **employee.setEid( 1201 );**

Answer (score 0):

Your id is auto generated, you don't have to pass it when inserting a new row.
Remove the line `employee.setEid( 1201 );` and it should do it. You should take a look at entity lifecycle. https://www.javabullets.com/jpa-entity-lifecycle/

Comment: Thank you for the response. When I remove the setId line, I get a several bunch of other errors, such as -- org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: error performing isolated work and java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=21) Table 'jpadb.hibernate_sequence' doesn't exist